# How to use chrome devtool protocol to solve element highlighting

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, protocols, highlight

I have got **vue** from Vue, now the problem is I want to write a Chrome Element like plugin through **vue**, the problem is how to highlight the element by selected tag, I don't know enough about chrome devtool protocol, I don't know if there is anyone who is deeper in I don't know enough about the chrome devtool protocol, and I was wondering if there is anyone who is deeper in this area and can guide me.